# How to update facebook status by http request

Tags: php, http, api, facebook, post

I try to send http request like:

```
"POST http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.users.setStatus&api_key=762ec91e7987aaeaee7e2cdfdfcb3c30&call_id=$call_id&sig=$s&v=1.0&uid=1533439618&status=44 HTTP/1.1";
```

but I receive nothing...

in twitter I success:

```
"POST ht tp://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?status=123123 HTTP/1.1"'
```

I must use it in this way ,because of GFW...

Comment: Please reformat your post to make it more readable.

Comment: No, please **format** it to make it more readable, not just add more text.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has a [defined API](http://developers.facebook.com/) that you can use.